# grep string between two other strings as delimiters

Tags: regex, powershell, grep

I have to do a report on how many times a certain CSS class appears in the content of our pages (over 10k pages). The trouble is, the header and footer contains that class, so a grep returns every single page.

So, how do I grep for content?

EDIT: I am looking for if a page has `list-unstyled` between `<main>` and `</main>`

So do I use a regular expression for that grep? or do I need to use PowerShell to have more functionality?

I have grep at my disposal and PowerShell, but I could use a portable software if that is my only option.

Ideally, I would get a report (.txt or .csv) with pages and line numbers where the class shows up, but just a list of the pages themselves would suffice.

EDIT: Progress

I now have this in PowerShell

```
$files = get-childitem -recurse -path w:\test\york\ -Filter *.html 
foreach ($file in $files)
{
$htmlfile=[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($file.fullName)
$regex="(?m)<main([\w\W]*)</main>"
if ($htmlfile -match $regex) { 
    $middle=$matches[1] 
    [regex]::Matches($middle,"list-unstyled")
    Write-Host $file.fullName has matches in the middle:
}
}
```

Which I run with this command `.\FindStr.ps1 | Export-csv C:\Tools\text.csv`

it outputs the filename and path with string in the console, put does not add anything to the CSV. How can I get that added in?

Comment: Showing some examples of the header and footer may help the accuracy of answers.

Comment: Giving a small sample will give the community something to chew on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What [Ansgar Wiechers' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30939380/3829407) says is good advice. Don't string search html files. I don't have a problem with it but it is worth noting that not all html files are the same and regex searches can produce flawed results. If tools exists that are aware of the file content structure you should use them.

I would like to take a simple approach that reports all files that have enough occurrences of the text `list-unstyled` in all html files in a given directory. You expect there to be 2? So if more than that show up then there is enough. I would have done a more complicated regex solution but since you want the line number as well I came up with this compromise.

```
$pattern = "list-unstyled"
Get-ChildItem C:\temp -Recurse -Filter *.html | 
    Select-String $pattern | 
    Group-Object Path | 
    Where-Object{$_.Count -gt 2} | 
    ForEach-Object{
        $props = @{
            File = $_.Group | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Path
            PatternFound = ($_.Group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LineNumber) -join ";"
        }

        New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $props
    }
```

`Select-String` is a `grep` like tool that can search files for string. It reports the located line number in the file which I why we are using it here.

You should get output that looks like this on your PowerShell console.

```
File                                                                           PatternFound                                                                  
----                                                                           ------------                                                                  
C:\temp\content.html                                                           4;11;54
```

Where 4,11,54 is the lines where the text was found. The code filters out results where the count of lines is less than 3. So if you expect it once in the header and footer those results should be excluded.

Comment: That works great. If I didn't care about line number, what would be the regex solution?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use string matches for something like this. Analyze the DOM instead. That should allow you to exclude headers and footers by selecting the appropriate root element.

```
$ie = New-Object -COM 'InternetExplorer.Application'

$url = '...'
$classname = 'list-unstyled'

$ie.Navigate($url)
do { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 } until ($ie.ReadyState -eq 4)

$root = $ie.Document.getElementsById('content-element-id')
$hits = $root.getElementsByTagName('*') | ? { $_.ClassName -eq $classname }

$hits.Count  # number of occurrences of $classname below content element
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a regexp that will be suitable for multiline match. The regexp `"(?m)<!-- main content -->([\w\W]*)<!-- end content -->"` matches a multiline content delimited by your comments, with `(?m)` part meaning that this regexp has multiline option enabled. The group `([\w\W]*)` matches *everything* between your comments, and also enables you to query `$matches[1]` which will contain your "main text" without headers and footers.

```
$htmlfile=[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($fileToGrep)
$regex="(?m)<!-- main content -->([\w\W]*)<!-- end content -->"
if ($htmlfile -match $regex) { 
    $middle=$matches[1] 
    [regex]::Matches($middle,"list-unstyled")
}
```

This is only an example of how should you parse the file. You populate `$fileToGrep` with a file name which you desire to parse, then run this snippet to receive a string that contains all the `list-unstyled` strings in the middle of that file.

Comment: And how would I run this?

Comment: how would I make it scan all the .html in a directory?, and dump results in txt file?

Comment: @Vesper It might just be a language issue but that comment comes off as crass and sarcastic.

Comment: @vesper, sorry about the question, I am not very familiar with powershell.

Comment: @JonYork Okay, you've done *almost* right, but in order to get the full path to file, you need to read from `$file.fullName`. `$htmlfile=[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($file.fullName)`

Comment: Cool, that works. It just gives me a number of times that it occurs. How would I get it to give me the files names/path it occurs in?

Thanks!

Comment: You can echo the required data in the cycle, say add `"$($file.fullName) has matches in the middle:` as a string expression on a separate line just before `[regex]::Matches` line, also if you need, you can export `$middle` somewhere to work, say you can `Out-File` it to a file with a generated name: `$middle | out-file "$($file.basename)-middle.txt"` for example.

Comment: Powershell is one heck of a powerhouse when it comes to doing something quickly without using extra tools. I think you should dig around it a bit more to make proper use of it in your routine work, but there's a real lot to find and there's a command line to sketch examples without big hassle that's usually involved when coding big.

Comment: please see updated post with problem getting the text to appear in CSV file

Comment: In order to make a CSV, you need your script to return table-formatted (structured) data. Also, `Write-Host` output never gets down the pipeline. You can return custom objects by using the following syntax: `New-Object PSObject -property @{"P1"="V1";"P2"="V2";...}` This should reside on a single line without any wrapping commands, so the output object will appear as the result of your script. You will need to include fullnames and match positions (up to the entire result of `[regex]::Matches()`, this is also possible).