# Regex is not matching pattern, only the individual parts

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to search for this expression:

```
<main([\w\W]*)list-unstyled([\w\W]*)</main>
```

This expression works perfectly in Sublime Text, Notepad++ Etc, and does exactly what I want. Look between  for list-unstyled.

My script below works with: `list-unstyled, <main, </main>, <main([\w\W]*), ([\w\W]*)</main>`

but not `<main([\w\W]*)</main>` , let alone what I really want, `<main([\w\W]*)list-unstyled([\w\W]*)</main>` , or better yet

```
<main([\w\W]*)$pattern([\w\W]*)</main>
```

How can I get it to work with that expression?

This is my code so far:

```
param(
    [string]$pattern,
    [string]$path  
    )
Get-ChildItem -path $path -Recurse -Filter *.html | 
    Select-String $pattern | 
    Group-Object Path | 
    ForEach-Object{
        $props = @{
            File = $_.Group | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Path
            PatternFound = ($_.Group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LineNumber) -join ";"
        }

        New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $props
    }
```

Sample code from a page

```
<main class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3" property="mainContentOfPage" role="main">
<h1 property="name" id="wb-cont">Divulgation d’opérations à déclarer </h1>
<div class="wb-share text-right mrgn-tp-lg mrgn-bttm-lg"></div><h2>Le saviez-vous?</h2>
<p>Les opérations à déclarer doivent être divulguées à l’Agence du revenu du Canada (ARC).</p>
<h2>Qu’est-ce qu’une opération à déclarer?</h2>
<p>Il s’agit d’un type particulier d’évitement fiscal qui consiste en une opération menée seule, ou dans le cadre d’une série d’opérations, et visant à éviter de payer de l’impôt. Elle doit répondre à au moins deux des trois critères suivants&#160;:</p>
<ol>
    <li>Le promoteur ou le conseiller fiscal de l’opération a le droit de recevoir des honoraires qui sont fondés sur ce qui suit&#160;:
    <ol class="lst-lwr-alph">
        <li>le montant de l’avantage fiscal;</li>
        <li>l’obtention de l’avantage fiscal;</li>
        <li>le nombre de personnes qui prennent part à l’opération ou qui ont pu profiter des conseils du promoteur ou du conseiller fiscal au sujet des conséquences fiscales de l’opération.</li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Le promoteur ou le conseiller fiscal de l’opération obtient le «&#160;droit à la confidentialité&#160;», qui vous empêche de divulguer des renseignements sur les détails ou la structure de l’opération.</li>
    <li>Vous, la personne qui conclut l’opération en votre nom, le promoteur ou le conseiller fiscal se prévaut ou s’est prévalu d’une «&#160;protection contractuelle&#160;». Il s’agit de toute forme de protection contre l’échec de l’opération ou qui donne droit au paiement de dépenses (y compris d’impôt, de pénalités, d’intérêts ou d’un montant semblable) qui peuvent être engagées en cas de différend à l’égard de l’avantage fiscal.</li>
</ol>
<h2>Qui doit divulguer des opérations à déclarer?</h2>
<p>Si vous concluez une opération à déclarer pour vous‑mêmes ou au profit d’une autre personne, vous devez la divulguer. Les promoteurs et les conseillers fiscaux sont aussi tenus de le faire.</p>
<h2>Quel est le processus pour divulguer une opération à déclarer?</h2>
<p>Que vous soyez un particulier, une société, une fiducie ou une société de personnes, vous devez remplir une déclaration de renseignements et l’envoyer à l’Agence du revenu du Canada. Vous devez produire le <a href="/F/pbg/tf/rc312/">formulaire&#160;RC312, Déclaration de renseignements sur les opérations à déclarer</a>, au plus tard le&#160;30&#160;juin suivant l’année civile au cours de laquelle l’opération est devenue pour la première fois une opération à déclarer. Ce formulaire doit être produit séparément de votre déclaration de revenus et de toute autre déclaration de renseignements.</p>
<h2>Quelles sont les conséquences si on ne déclare pas une opération?</h2>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li><strong>Pénalité&#160;:</strong> Si vous, ou votre représentant, ne produisez pas le formulaire&#160;RC312 dans le délai prévu, vous devrez, ainsi que chaque personne tenue de le produire, payer une pénalité, même s’il a eu entente sur qui devait le produire. Le montant de la pénalité est égal au montant total des honoraires à l’égard de l’opération que le promoteur ou le conseiller fiscal a le droit de recevoir.</li>
    <li><strong>Suspension de l’avantage fiscal :</strong> En plus de la pénalité, l’avantage fiscal est refusé jusqu’à ce que l’obligation de produire le formulaire&#160;RC312 soit satisfaite et que la pénalité et les intérêts cumulés soient payés.</li>
    <li><strong>Période de nouvelle cotisation prolongée :</strong> Si le formulaire&#160;RC312 n’a pas été produit dans le délai prévu, la période pendant laquelle l’ARC peut établir une nouvelle cotisation est prolongée de trois ans suivant la date où il a été produit.</li>
</ul>
<p>Pour en savoir plus, consultez le document d’information de&#160;2013 intitulé <a href="/nwsrm/fctshts/2013/m08/fs130830-fra.html">Nouvelles exigences en matière de déclaration&#160;: opérations à déclarer</a> ou le <a href="/F/pbg/tf/rc312/">formulaire RC312, Déclaration de renseignements sur les opérations à déclarer</a>.</p>
<p class="text-center">-30-</p>
<h2>Soyez branché</h2>
<p>Pour recevoir des mises à jour lorsque nous ajoutons de nouveaux renseignements à notre site Web, vous pouvez&#160;:</p>
<ul class="list-unstyled mrgn-lft-md">
    <li><img alt="" src="/images/scl-md/16px/twitter.gif" height="16" /> Suivre l'ARC sur Twitter - <a href="http://twitter.com/agencerevcan">@AgenceRevCan</a></li>
    <li><img alt="" src="/images/scl-md/16px/email.gif" height="16" /> Vous abonner à une <a href="/esrvc-srvce/mllst/sbscrb-fra.html">liste d'envois électroniques</a> de l'ARC</li>
    <li><img alt="" src="/images/scl-md/16px/rss.gif" height="16" /> Ajouter nos <a href="/esrvc-srvce/rss/menu-fra.html">fils RSS</a> &#224; votre lecteur de nouvelles</li>
</ul>
<p><img alt="" src="/images/scl-md/16px/youtube.gif" height="16" /> Vous pouvez également visiter notre <a href="http://www.youtube.com/agencerevcan">canal YouTube</a> pour voir des vidéos sur l'impôt.</p>
<p><a href="/nwsrm/md-fra.html">Renseignements aux médias</a></p>
<p><br />
<!-- InstanceEndEditable --></p>
<dl property="dateModified" id="wb-dtmd">
<dt>Date de modification :</dt>
<dd>
<time>2015-06-11</time>
</dd>
</dl>
</main>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I see you are working on this again. Can you include a small sample of text. Just in case we need something to play with. That is always useful with these types of questions. There are characters that need escaping in there I would have thought.

Comment: From the looks of it this is a multi line regex .You do not have and modifiers that would allow for a search like that and I think your `select-string` is reacting to each line not the text as a whole. Do you need the line numbers? I don't think you will get them how this needs to be fixed.

Comment: I could live without the line numbers in this application.

Comment: I think that using regex is probably not the right approach for this. Using an XML or HTML parser might be far easier. It's also not entirely clear what you're trying to find / extract. Are you looking for elements with a `list-unstyled` class?

Comment: @arco444 look at his previous question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938865/grep-string-between-two-other-strings-as-delimiters it has more of the logic behind this. This looks based on my solution which was not intended to be used exactly this way

Comment: try prefixing your pattern with (?m)

Comment: @Les That is that start of the problem but will not fix the entire issue for how Select-String is being used here.

Comment: Sorry about all this guys, very new (less than a week) with powershell, boss asking for impossible answers in impossible timelines, you know how it goes. Thanks for all the input you can provide!

Comment: @JonYork are you *only* trying to test if the string `list-unstyled` exists in some text between `<main>` and `</main>`? Is there any other information you need to extract or is it a simple true/false result you need?

Comment: True/false is good enough. If I can just get a list of files with list-unstyled between the main tags when I Export-Csv test.csv would be awesome.

Comment: @arco444 Ansgars answer in the last question might be the ticket FYI

Comment: @Matt ok, I see that Select-String applies the pattern to each line and has no capability to apply a pattern across more than one line, so select-string is the wrong choice

Comment: @YonYork you can instantiate a regex object like so, $regex = [regex] '(?m)<main([\w\W]*)list-unstyled([\w\W]*)</main>'  and then loop doing this...   $txt = type $htmlFile; $regex.Match($txt).Success

Comment: @les.... No. If used correctly it's fine. The issue here is how it is being called in the pipeline. You can use it on whole string. It reacts to files and arrays differently.

Comment: @Matt - I don't follow, but using the object and the following PS script, I get the output I think the OP is looking for ... get-childitem *.htm | foreach { $txt = type $_ ; $props = @{ status = $regex.Match($txt).Success; path = $_ } ; new-object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $props }

Comment: it lists status and path with expected true/false

Comment: 1st if you have an answer post it as such. Code in comments is horrible. 2nd I was responding to your comment about your interpretation of `Select-String`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81307/discussion-between-les-and-matt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like everyone is suggesting here in comments and in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938865/grep-string-between-two-other-strings-as-delimiters?lq=1) you should use html parsers if possible. I don't have the best experience with them so I will try to update this code to comply with your needs.

The main problem you are having is that when you pass a file object to `Select-String` it will be read in a string *array* and not a single string. Both approaches have their merits but in your case this is not what you want since you need to do a multi-line match. Since line number is not important this can be simplified

```psh
param(
    [string]$pattern,
    [string]$path  
    )
Get-ChildItem -path $path -Recurse -Filter *.html | 
    Where-Object{
        Select-String -InputObject (Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String) $pattern -Quiet
    }
}
```

What that will do is use `Get-Content` to read in the entire file as one string with the help of `| Out-String` then we use a slightly tweaked version of your regex. We needed to escape a backslash and add a couple of modifiers. `</main>` became `<\/main>` in the pattern below as well as adding `(?sm)`.

```
(?sm)<main([\w\W]*)list-unstyled([\w\W]*)<\/main>
```

Since we use `-Quiet` with `Select-String` we only get a boolean result. Using that inside the `Where-Object` clause allow only the fileinfo object matching the criteria to pass thru the pipe. That way if you had to say.. move the files you can just tack on a `Move-Item` without the need of another `foreach-object` loop.

You have this as a script I will presume? If you want to filter this output you would need to add a pipe `| Select Fullname | Export-CSV "C:\somepath"`. Whether you put this into the function or use it like this `script.ps1 pattern path | Select Fullname | Export-CSV "C:\somepath"` is up to you.

Comment: That's bang on. Any way we can get it to just give me a file path + filename, instead of all the other columns we get when we just the Export-Csv? If no, no biggie, I can clean that up. Thanks!

Comment: @JonYork You're welcome. Consider marking questions as accepted if you feel they solved your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a PS script that might get you closer to what you are looking for.  Adjust the logic for your situation.

```
$regex = [regex] '(?m)<main([\w\W]*)list-unstyled([\w\W]*)</main>'
get-childitem *.htm |
    foreach { $txt = type $_ ;
              $props = @{
                  status = $regex.Match($txt).Success;
                  path = $_
              } ;
              new-object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $props
    }


status path
------ ----
  True C:\Users\Les\testfile.htm
 False C:\Users\Les\testfile2.htm
 False C:\Users\Les\testfile3.htm
```